# Is it possible to know which database takes up the most storage on my disk

Tags: postgresql

I found the largest folder under my postgreSQL storage directory is `/usr/local/var/postgres/base/209510`

How could I know this data is belonging to which datatable ?

In the other way, is it possible to know which database or datatable takes up  the most storege.

Because there's almost no free space on my SSD disk

Comment: Go to the documentation on the website: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ and search for "database size". Look through the first five or six results and you'll see a number of options. The simplest option is "\l+" from psql. It's always worth checking the manuals for trivial factual questions like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the largest database in postgreSQL :

```
SELECT datname, pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size(datname)) db_size
FROM pg_database
ORDER BY db_size;
```

Comment: The order by "pretty formatted textstring" does nog give the numeric order. Better would be:  `order by pg_database_size(datname)`

Comment: yes, it's better to remove the `pg_size_pretty` function, but i'm still appreciating your reply

Answer (score 1):

In psql, you can use the `\l+` command to get a nice summary of databases with sizes.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is from within an SQL prompt - there are several examples of queries you can run listed at https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Disk_Usage and one for the largest tables in current database is copied below for posterity.

```
SELECT nspname || '.' || relname AS "relation",
    pg_size_pretty(pg_relation_size(C.oid)) AS "size"
  FROM pg_class C
  LEFT JOIN pg_namespace N ON (N.oid = C.relnamespace)
  WHERE nspname NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema')
  ORDER BY pg_relation_size(C.oid) DESC
  LIMIT 20;
```

Comment: is it possible to find the largest database in postgreSQL thanks